# how to reduce button click event code in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs6

I have 1 to 64 buttons called(instance name) b1 - b64. I need to add mouse click event to every buttons.My current code like this....

```
b1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, btn1click);
function btn1click(event:MouseEvent)
{
 var e = b1;
}
b2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, btn2click);
function btn2click(event:MouseEvent)
{
 var e = b2;
}
b3.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, btn3click);
function btn3click(event:MouseEvent)
{
 var e = b3;
}
.......
```

I need to reduce that repetition.

Comment: Couldn't you make an array of them?

Comment: Similar question as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36660246/how-to-write-an-object-name-with-a-variable-for-iteration-in-as3/36661586

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a loop to attach the event listeners to the buttons:

```
for (var i:int = 1; i <= 64; i++) {
    this['b' + i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, btnClick);
}
```

And use a single listener function:

```
function btnClick(event:MouseEvent):void {
    trace(event.currentTarget + ' was clicked.');
}
```

Comment: trace(event.currentTarget.name + ' was clicked.'); //Edit

Comment: @VirajTharinda You know it.